# Dplyr to calculate mean, SD, and graph multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with columns

[Time, var1, var2, var3, var4...varN]

I need to calculate mean/SE per Time for each var1, var2...var n , and I want to do this programmatically for all variables, rather than 1 at a time which would involve a lot of copy-pasting.

Section 8.2.3 here https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html is close to what I want but my below code:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 3))
x[1,1] = 1
x[1,2] = 2
x[1,3] = 3
x[2,1] =4
x[2,2] = 5
x[2,3] = 6
names(x)[1] <- "time"
names(x)[2] <- "var1"
names(x)[3] <- "var2"

grouped_mean3 <- function(.data, ...) {
  print(.data)
  summary_vars <- enquos(...)
  print(summary_vars)
  summary_vars <- purrr::map(summary_vars, function(var) {
    expr(mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE))
  })
  print(summary_vars)

  .data %>%
    group_by(time)
    summarise(!!!summary_vars)  # Unquote-splice the list
}
grouped_mean3(x, var("var1"), var("var2"))
```

Yields

```
Error in !summary_vars : invalid argument type
```

And the original cause is "Must group by variables found in `.data`." and it finds a column that isn't in the dummy "x" that I generated for the purposes of testing. I have no idea what's happening, sadly.

How do I actually extract the mean from the new summary_vars and add it to the .data table? summary_vars becomes something like

```
[[1]]
mean(~var1, na.rm = TRUE)

[[2]]
mean(~var2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Which seems close, but needs evaluation. How do I evaluate this? !!! wasn't working.

For what it's worth, I tried plugging the example in dplyr into this R engine https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/starwars.html and it didn't work either.

Help?

End goal would be a table along the lines of

[Time, var1mean, var2mean, var3mean, var4mean...]

Comment: Your code will give a different error, `object 'summary_vars' not found`. Please make sure your code is actually reproducible.

Comment: add `summary_vars <- enquos(...)` to the first line, and remove the `vars` in the call

Comment: Smthg like `library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(Time) %>%
     summarise(across(var1:varN, mean))`

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk I added that yet still see "Error in !summary_vars : invalid argument type." Example updated, though.

Comment: @Axeman I updated the page to have code you can copy paste, including generating a dummy table of data to induce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
library(dplyr)

grouped_mean3 <- function(.data, ...) {
  vars <- c(...)
  
  .data %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarise(across(all_of(vars), mean))
}

grouped_mean3(x, 'var1')

#   time  var1mean
#  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1         2
#2     4         5

grouped_mean3(x, 'var1', 'var2')

#   time var1mean var2mean
#  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1        2        3
#2     4        5        6
```

Comment: Thank you - that's getting me close, but unfortunately I'm still failing to understand something -- that code does not give me a table with means, it gives me "x" when I run it.

x %>% group_by(time) %>% summarize(mean_value = mean(var1))

The above phrase will find me the "mean" of var1 by time. I'm basically trying to figure out how to make "var1" a variable that can be passed in (e.g. as a string) and then that way I can add columns to the original data frame "x" of mean_var1, mean_var2, mean_var3...

Comment: @RNewbie Did you store the output in the new variable? like this `x1 <- grouped_mean3(x, 'var1')` and then check `x1` for results. If it does not work as intended for you, I would suggest to give a better example and show expected output for it so that we know what you are expecting.

Comment: FWIW this doesn't resolve my original question, but this: "x %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(names(x)[-1]), funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))" seems to get me all the means I desire. So that's a start.

Comment: @RNewbie My answer does provide output similar to your end goal. I have updated the answer to show that. If that is not what you want you need to update your post with your exact expected output and better data. I don't see any other "original question" in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
x %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('var')), ~mean(.,na.rm=T)) %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('var')),funs(paste(.,"mean"))) %>%
  merge(x)
```

With your data (from your question) following is the output:

```
  time var1mean var2mean var1 var2
1    1        2        3    2    3
2    4        5        6    5    6
```